# DEPRECATED - Laravel : How to localize dates within views with Carbon

Tags: laravel, deprecated, php-carbon

I'm trying to localize **Carbon** dates in a view in different languages with no success so far.

I retrieve dates from a Model and send them to a view:

```
Route::get('/tables/setup', function(){
     $now=  Date::now('Europe/Paris');

     $active_tasks = GanttTask::whereDate('start_date', '<',  $now)
        ->whereDate('end_date', '>', $now)
        ->get();

     return view('my_view', compact('active_tasks'));

   });
```

and can easily display them in 'my_view':

```
  @foreach($active_tasks as $active_task)

     {{$active_task->start_date->format('l j F Y H:i:s')}}  //Friday 26 January 2018 09:19:54

     @endforeach
```

But I can not manage to render them in the desired language.

I tried adding `Carbon::setLocale('it');` in the route or in the view with no effect.

**EDIT:** 
slight error in my blade call `{{$active_task->start_date->format('l j F Y H:i:s')}}` instead of `{{$active_task->format('l j F Y H:i:s')}}`

Comment: Carbon::setLocale('fr')->now()->format('l j F Y H:i:s');

Comment: or Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the php function `setlocale` before setting the localized format in Carbon.

> Unfortunately the base class DateTime does not have any localization support. To begin localization support a formatLocalized($format) method was added. The implementation makes a call to strftime using the current instance timestamp. If you first set the current locale with PHP function setlocale() then the string returned will be formatted in the correct locale.

Examples from the docs:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Mittwoch 21 Mai 1975
setlocale(LC_TIME, '');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Wednesday 21 May 1975
```

Comment: Ok I see the mistake about using `format()` . Changed my code with now effect so far but I keep trying

Comment: Arg! 'German' was not a valid language in my php config. That's why it didn't work on the first try. Weird example they gave!

Comment: You can list the installed locales with `locale -a`. To install a new one, [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/76106/323990).

Comment: It is late to answer but for those who come later to this question. the setlocale() will only apply changes to the formatLocalized() method. To translate months' names I created a gist here that I think its the only way to be able to localize Carbon's custom formats.https://gist.github.com/ebrahimahmadi/ac9b08c857065d36c1fcefb0ea8e5733

Comment: P.S. Deprecated as of PHP8.1. isoFormat() should be used instead

Answer (score 1):

Ok, everything is fixed.

In the top of the view:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'IT_it');
```

And then the blade call:

```
{{$active_task->start_date->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')}}
```

All credits to @Btl

Comment: formatLocalized DEPRECATED

Comment: 5 years later, great comment...

Comment: Hi Sebastien D, my comment is to help others that found this. This post is high up in the search engine results. It's good to know that it is DEPRECATED now.
So, what if it's an old post?... people are still looking for the same info from 10 years ago or more. 
@sebastien-d

Comment: @ChrisDeDavidMindflowAU, just edited the topic name, is it more clear ?

Comment: Great idea, it will be more clear and helpful to others.